# Android : Using amazom s3 TransferManager with UIL

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-image, universal-image-loader

I'd like to start using Amazon `TransferManager` with UIL. 
Currentlly i'm using UIL the following way I've extended the `BaseImageDownloader` class and I provide the input stream

```
return client.getObject(req).getObjectContent();
```

and when using the UIL I just provide my downloader class to the UIL configurations.

How can I migrate it to use TransferManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransferManager` doesn't give you access to an `InputStream` while a download is in progress so it may not be a good match for your usage.  One approach would be to download to a `File` first then create an `InputStream` on that.  This example doesn't have exception handling, but shows that approach.

```
File outputFile = new File("/path/to/file");
Download download = transferManager.download(req, outputFile);
download.waitForCompletion();
return new FileInputStream(outputFile);
```